# Optimistic concurrency across the board or just the table which is causing deadlocks?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, concurrency, deadlock

I am working with a legacy EF system which is giving me some deadlocks on updates.  It uses pessimistic concurrency.  I want to move away from that and therefore I have allowed for the table which was updated to support optimistic concurrency.  I am wondering whether I need to implement optimistic concurrency through all tables or just the ones which I believe is being deadlocked (the table which is being updated)?  Any ideas are appreciated.

Regards,
Ruskin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not state the RDBMS, nor did you state the quality of your data.

Some RDBMS allow different stages of locking and you should really know what is happening behind the scenes. If you deal with sensible data (like I do) the **data integrity** must always stand **before** performance or annoying behaviour like a deadlock. This depends on the data you are storing. Sometimes one can accept the risk of small integrity breaks...

I would **never** change from pessimistic locking to optimistic just to avoid deadlocks...

You could run into mistakes without exceptions. Everything seems to run great, but some time later you find, that your data is broken...

My advise: Use kind of a profiler to understand what is really happening. Most deadlocks have their reason in bad structures. Most deadlocks are easy to avoid if you change the process. But this - especially in connection with legacy software - might be difficult.

Could be, that your legacy software calls code within your RDBMS (e.g. stored procedures) Could be, that your can change something there without changing the calling software...

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that, I am using SQL (tagged), not sure what you mean by "quality" of data.  I understand that deadlocks are not the devil and sometimes you can't avoid them.  So it's all about good management of deadlocks and your data and writing better application code :)

Comment: @Ruskin, with "quality" I was speaking about the "kind" of data you are dealing with. Transactional, financial data is some other stuff than e.g. weather measuring data. In my job - as I said before - data integrity is more important than performance.

Comment: @Ruskin, one more point: I asked you about your RDBMS, your answer was "SQL (tagged)". It would be necessary to state your product (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle...) and the version. Especially question about locking might be quite different between those products...